# Boost linking error after updating g++ version

Tags: gcc, boost, g++, linker-errors

my program was OK to build a few days back. But after I update my gcc/g++ I got compiling errors:

```
CMakeFiles/tripleClassification.dir/src/tripleClassification.cpp.o: In function `boost::program_options::typed_value<std::string, char>::xparse(boost::any&, std::vector<std::string, std::allocator<std::string> > const&) const':
tripleClassification.cpp:(.text._ZNK5boost15program_options11typed_valueISscE6xparseERNS_3anyERKSt6vectorISsSaISsEE[_ZNK5boost15program_options11typed_valueISscE6xparseERNS_3anyERKSt6vectorISsSaISsEE]+0x19): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::validate(boost::any&, std::vector<std::string, std::allocator<std::string> > const&, std::string*, int)'
```

I googled it, it seems to have something to do with gcc version. Can anyone tell me how to change my cmake file to make it work?

Comment: Looks like Boost library you have is incompatible with new gcc version. If you have built Boost from sources, rebuild it. If you have installed it from repo, update it.

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-5.3.0/gcc/Compatibility.html

Comment: Actually, we need a [tag:c++-faq] entry on ABI compatibility, ODR and UB relations. With a reference to https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#i26-if-you-want-a-cross-compiler-abi-use-a-c-style-subset and stuff like that.